# Rendering painted lines as nodes in Cocos

Tags: objective-c, ipad, drawing, cocos2d-iphone

I'm working on a drawing app for iPad using Cocos-iOS and I'm having performance issues with drawing lines as a type of `CCNode`. I understand that using `draw` in a node causes it to be called every time the canvas is repainted and the current code is very heavy if used every time:

```
for (LineNodePoint *point in self.points) {
    start = end;
    end = point;
    if (start && end) {
        float distance = ccpDistance(start.point, end.point);
        if (distance > 1) {
            int d = (int)distance;
            float difx = end.point.x - start.point.x;
            float dify = end.point.y - start.point.y;
            for (int i = 0; i < d; i++) {
                float delta = i / distance;

                [[self.brush sprite] setPosition:ccp(start.point.x + (difx * delta), start.point.y + (dify * delta))];
                [[self.brush sprite] visit];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Very heavy...

I either need a better way to draw the lines or to be able to cache the drawing as a raster.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I've found some useful information regarding CCRenderTexture where I could draw the line to that and then save it as a drawing cache, How well would this work?

Answer (score 0):

How about ccDrawLine or CCMutableTexture? CCMutableTexture is for manipulating pixels using CCRenderTexture internally as you said.

- ccDrawLine

  - [cocos2d for iPhone 1.0.0 API reference](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/1.0.0/_c_c_drawing_primitives_8h.html)
- CCMutableTexture

  - [Fast set/getPixel for an opengl texture?](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/2449)
  - [[render texture] pixel manipulation (integrated CCMutableTexture functionality)](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/11241)